# Returning sum of array elements perl

Tags: perl

I have an MyArray whoes content are "200 500 800 100 " in perl . I need function which return me first 200, second iteration it should return me 200+500, next time it should return me 200+500+800,until it has sumup all the elements.

```
   foreach my $i (0 .. $#MyArray)
   {
       @MyArray = (1..$i);     
       $sum += $_ for @MyArray;
   }
```

I am trying to do something as mentioned above, but its not returning any $sum

Comment: See [List::Util::sum](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html).

Comment: What do you mean by "return me 200+500"?  Do you want the routine to actually return a running total or are you only interested in the final sum of the numbers in the array?

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
use List::Util qw/sum/;
my @arr = (200, 500, 800, 100);
say sum(@arr[0..$_]) for (0..$#arr);
```

**Output:**

```
200
700
1500
1600
```

Documentation about [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
my $array = [200, 500, 800, 100];
my @sum_array;
my $iter_sum = 0;
for my $each (@$array) {
    $iter_sum += $each;
    push @sum_array, $iter_sum;
}
return \@sum_array;
```

you can get the sum in the `@sum_array`

Answer (score 0):

```
@MyArray = (1..10);
foreach my $i (0 .. $#MyArray)
{
        $sum += $_ for @MyArray;
}
print "sum: $sum"
```

Output:

> sum: 550

About your code: Maybe you need to put the array definition out of loop